# Linux USB audio volume problem

Tags: linux, audio, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Linux/Windows 8 system with a pair of KEF X300A speakers connected to the machine via a USB port.

After each reboot from Windows the maximum volume obtainable from the speakers in Linux is very low. Disconnecting and then re-connecting the USB cable resolves the problem.

This is probably caused by something the Windows driver does to the speakers themselves rather than a pulseaudio/snd_usb_audio, but I would very much like to avoid the need for the physical access to the USB cable and restore the volume level in software. Things I've tried:

- Disable and re-enable the card in pulseaudio
- Reset the device via ioctl's `USBDEVFS_RESET`
- Re-connect the interface via ioctl's `USBDEVFS_DISCONNECT` and `USBDEVFS_CONNECT`

All of them leave the maximum volume unchanged.

Can anyone suggest a different approach?